# Details on Topcon theodolite data format (<3595959+3595959+****d094)

Tags: land-survey

I am interfacing to a Topcon DT-102 (circa 1995) digital theodolite and wonder if anyone can help with the transmission format.  It is perhaps shared with Sokkia or Leica/Wild.

**Background**

The unit has only the ability to measure horizontal and vertical angles.
By trial and error I have found it is transmitting at 1200 baud 7 data even parity, and continuously sends messages twice a second.

When the LDC display shows 0° 53' 10" vertical and 7° 46' 40" horizontal measurements, the unit transmits:

```
<0005310+0074640+****d094
 |      |       |    |
 |      |       |    + checksum?
 |      |       + distance?
 |      + horizontal measurement sdddhhmm
 + vertical measurement dddhhmm
```

(each message is then followed by ETX, CR, LF, ie ASCII values 3, 13, 10).

**Question**

Does anybody have any details on this format?

Specifically

1. What is this format called?
2. Do you have a reference for it and a detailed specification?
3. What does `+****` represent?  Perhaps a distance for a similar model with a rangefinder?
4. What is `d094`? A checksum?  Any details?